# I messed up my windows bootloader BIOS doesn't show any more

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, bootloader

I partitioned my drive and installed ubuntu. I wanted the space back so I deleted the ubuntu partition and attempted to restore the windows bootloader by running the install disk, troubleshooting and entering the following commands;

```
bootrec.exe /FixMbr
bootrec.exe /FixBoot
```

After running the second command, the prompt said I didn't not have access. I reloaded my pc and now I can't even access the BIOS. How can I fix this?

Edit: I am able to load from a windows install USB drive but it is unable to detect my hard drive

Comment: **Moderator Warning** - please do not use obscenities in your posts. I've removed it for you. Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](https://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"

Comment: I'm pretty sure you corrupted your hard drive's partition table when you did `/FixMbr`. Windows 10 uses GTP-style partition tables by default (as do modern linux distros)... not DOS/MBR-style. You're probably going to need to use data recovery software to recover any vital data from your hard drive then format and reinstall from scratch. BTW, if you couldn't access the BIOS then you wouldn't be able to boot USB devices either.

Comment: Restore from your last drive image.